# Is it possible to change sendmail behavior on "Host unknown" errors?

Tags: domain-name-system, smtp, sendmail

Sendmail 8.14.4

I had DNS issues resulting in a DNS server thinking that a hostname wasn't available (when in fact, it was available).

That resulted in the following delivery log entry in sendmail:

```
Jun  6 16:16:19 sm-box sendmail[27433]: v56NGJ68027430: to=<examplerecipient@foodomain123example.com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=esmtp, pri=171299, relay=foodomain123example.com., dsn=5.1.2, stat=Host unknown (Name server: foodomain123example.com.: host not found)    
Jun  2 16:16:19 sm-box sendmail[27433]: v56NGJ68027430: v56NGJ68027433: DSN: Host unknown (Name server: foodomain123example.com.: host not found)
```

sendmail behavior here makes sense. But I'm being asked by management if there's anyway that the sendmail messages could be queued (at least for an hour or two) before sendmail completely gives up.

This feels like something that would be mandated behavior in RFCs but I couldn't find specific references to it.

Comment: Could you post DNS results of DNS queries?  Sendmail should get "temporary problem" replies => sendmail should queue. So your DNS resolver (local caching name-servers) is broken or (slightly less likely) you found yet another sendmail bug.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip The issue isn't occurring any more so I can't provide the query.  That being said, I'm able to reproduce the general behavior pretty quickly.  Try sending a message to example@sldkfjlsdkfjsldkfjsldkjfsldkfjlsdkfjslkjflsdkjfslkdjflsdkjflsdkjflsdkjflskdjf.com    That domain doesn't exist and sendmail immediately gives up with a 5.1.2 error.  That's normal and expected but I'm wondering if it's configurable at all.

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Any ideas? Thanks. I'm suspecting that this is hard-coded as we normally wouldn't ever want a MTA to keep trying to send to a domain that is "unknown".

Comment: Sorry, I do not have time to check/verify your pretty good guesstimates.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many configuration options that will change timeouts related to email deliveries. If you have a look at http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/tweaking_config.html for example, you may need to fiddle with `confTO_RESOLVER_RETRY`